# ExpandableListView(Android): multiple viewTypes - passing data between them via onClickListener?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Okay, so here's my problem.  I have an expandableListView, and custom adapter.  I was able to setup the adapter to handle 2 different child viewTypes (one with a switch and one without).  I'm also using a ViewHolder to manage the views.

What I'm struggling with is how to affect the viewType without the switch from the viewType that has the switch.  Specifically the viewType with the switch is a childHeader that appears at the beginning of each group.  When the user toggles the switch I want to be able to change the color of the text of the rest of the children in the group (and disable selection of the row as well).

Because the toggle is inflated in rowType zero, it only sees other views that exist within the same viewType.

**Additionally: I need these updates to happen via the toggle switch in the zero viewType.  So when the user toggles the switch, all the views get affected.**

Is this something that I'll need to do in the activity?

Any ideas on how to do this would be much appreciated (please no suggestions to use 3rd party libraries).

Output example:

[image]

Please see the sample code below:

ADAPTER CODE:

```
public class NavDrawerExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private static final int CHILD_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int CHILD_LINE_ITEM = 1;

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

    private final Set<Pair<Long, Long>> mToggleSwitchedItems = new HashSet<Pair<Long, Long>>();

    public NavDrawerExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                          HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }

    //view holder class to store our textView
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        Switch childHeaderToggle;
    }

    //number of different types of views we're gonna inflate for the children
    @Override
    public int getChildTypeCount () {
        return 2;
    }

    //specify which viewType to inflate in the getView method
    @Override
    public int getChildType (int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        switch(childPosition) {
            case 0:
                return CHILD_HEADER;
            default:
                return CHILD_LINE_ITEM;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //declare our view and viewholder objects
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        String expandedListText;

        //define childType
        int childType = getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);
        //define the toggleTag position
        Pair<Long, Long> childHeaderToggleTag = new Pair<Long, Long>(getGroupId(groupPosition), getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (childType) {
                case CHILD_HEADER:
                    //inflate our layout and textview then setTag viewholder if the view is null
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_list_item_header, null);
                    viewHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItemChildHeader);
                    viewHolder.childHeaderToggle = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.toggle_allDevices);
                    viewHolder.textView.setText("All Teams");
                    break;
                case CHILD_LINE_ITEM:
                    expandedListText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition - 1);
                    //inflate our layout and textview then setTag viewholder if the view is null
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_list_item, null);
                    viewHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
                    viewHolder.textView.setText(expandedListText);
                    break;
                default:
                    expandedListText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition - 1);
                    //inflate our layout and textview then setTag viewholder if the view is null
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_list_item, null);
                    viewHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
                    viewHolder.textView.setText(expandedListText);
                    break;
            }
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            //otherwise if the view exists then gettag() our saved view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        //control the state of the child header toggle switch
        if (childPosition == 0) {
            viewHolder.childHeaderToggle.setTag(childHeaderToggleTag);
            // set switched on if groupId/childId is in switched list
            viewHolder.childHeaderToggle.setChecked(mToggleSwitchedItems.contains(childHeaderToggleTag));
            // set OnClickListener to handle checked switches
            viewHolder.childHeaderToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Switch cb = (Switch) v;
                    final Pair<Long, Long> tag = (Pair<Long, Long>) v.getTag();
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        mToggleSwitchedItems.add(tag);
                    } else {
                        mToggleSwitchedItems.remove(tag);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return (this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size() + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListView expandableListView;
NavDrawerExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
List<String> expandableListTitle;
HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
    expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
    expandableListAdapter = new NavDrawerExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

    expandableListView.setChoiceMode(expandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        //initialize int var
        int previousGroup = 0;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            //this conditional enables only one drop down group to open at a time
            if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            if (childPosition == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "All Teams", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                                + " -> "
                                + expandableListDetail.get(
                                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition - 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: In your adapter keep a SparseArray<Boolean> field. Pass the groupPosition value as a tag(Integer value) for viewHolder.childHeaderToggle. In the listener for the switch, use the SparseArray above and put the status of the switch: *sparseArray.put((Integer)cb.getTag(), cb.isChecked())* . Then further modify the getChildView() method to add an *else* clause to *if (childPosition == 0) {...* where you can modify the other rows as you wish by fetching the status of the switch of this group: *boolean switchStatus =  sparseArray.valueAt(groupPosition);...*

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Luksprog.  If I understand correctly what you suggested, then the views in rows other than zero will get changed however they won't change via the onClickListener.  I need the values to get updated as the switch is toggled.  Sorry maybe I should have been more specific, I was able to get the values changed by using a simple set() and get() method.  The problem was that the text colors won't update unless I re-open the group (which is when the getView would be called again). (that was my fault for not including that in my original post - so sorry about that)

Comment: Updated original post to include onClickListener

Comment: The other rows will change when the getChildView() method is called again. In the listener for the switch, after you set the switch status also call notifyDataSetChanged(). This lets the adapter know something changed and it will call the getChildView() again.

Comment: Ah okay, so really the key then is to add notifyDataSetChanged() to the listener for the switch and then we should see the updates?  Correct?  I'll play around using your suggestion and see if I can get it working.  If you have a moment to post a working code example I would be extra grateful.  Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: Okay.  So it looks like notifyDataSetChanged() was the magical missing piece.  I tried the version of this test project that used the get() and set() methods to pass the values and added notifyDataSetChanged() to the end of the switch listener and BAM!  The values are updating as expected.  Much appreciated!!  I'll try to post a working version to share.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  Here's the solution I came up with using notifyDataSetChanged() inside the switch listener.  Luksprog had a good (and probably more proper) solution for passing values between viewTypes, but I went with the set() get() methods that I had in a test version of this project.

Here's the updated Adapter Code:
(Pay particular attention to setChildtoggleCheckedState() and getChildToggleCheckedState() methods as well as where I put the notifyDataSetChanged())

```
public class NavDrawerExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private static final int CHILD_HEADER = 0;
private static final int CHILD_LINE_ITEM = 1;

private Context context;
private List<String> expandableListTitle;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

private final Set<Pair<Long, Long>> mToggleSwitchedItems = new HashSet<Pair<Long, Long>>();

public NavDrawerExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                      HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
    this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
}

//set the toggle switch state of the child header so we can access it in other layouts
private void setChildToggleCheckedState(boolean state) {
    this.childToggleHeaderState = state;
}

//get the toggle switch state of the child header toggle so we can access it in other layouts
public boolean getChildToggleCheckedState() {
    return childToggleHeaderState;
}

//view holder class to store our textView
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    Switch childHeaderToggle;
}

//number of different types of views we're gonna inflate for the children
@Override
public int getChildTypeCount () {
    return 2;
}

//specify which viewType to inflate in the getView method
@Override
public int getChildType (int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    switch(childPosition) {
        case 0:
            return CHILD_HEADER;
        default:
            return CHILD_LINE_ITEM;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //declare our view and viewholder objects
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    String expandedListText;

    //define childType
    int childType = getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);
    //define the toggleTag position
    Pair<Long, Long> childHeaderToggleTag = new Pair<Long, Long>(getGroupId(groupPosition), getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (childType) {
            case CHILD_HEADER:
                //inflate our layout and textview then setTag viewholder if the view is null
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_list_item_header, null);
                viewHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItemChildHeader);
                viewHolder.childHeaderToggle = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.toggle_allDevices);
                break;
            case CHILD_LINE_ITEM:
                expandedListText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition - 1);
                //inflate our layout and textview then setTag viewholder if the view is null
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_list_item, null);
                viewHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
                viewHolder.textView.setText(expandedListText);
                break;
            default:
                expandedListText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition - 1);
                //inflate our layout and textview then setTag viewholder if the view is null
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_list_item, null);
                viewHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
                viewHolder.textView.setText(expandedListText);
                break;
        }
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        //otherwise if the view exists then gettag() our saved view
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    //control the state of the child header toggle switch
    if (childPosition == 0) {
        viewHolder.childHeaderToggle.setTag(childHeaderToggleTag);
        // set switched on if groupId/childId is in switched list
        viewHolder.childHeaderToggle.setChecked(mToggleSwitchedItems.contains(childHeaderToggleTag));
        setChildToggleCheckedState(mToggleSwitchedItems.contains(childHeaderToggleTag));

        //depending on toggle state set our child header text colors
        if (!getChildToggleCheckedState()) {
            viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.navDrawerInactiveText));
        }
        else {
            viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.navDrawerDisabledText));
        }

        // set OnClickListener to handle checked switches
        viewHolder.childHeaderToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Switch cb = (Switch) v;
                final Pair<Long, Long> tag = (Pair<Long, Long>) v.getTag();
                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                setChildToggleCheckedState(true);
                    mToggleSwitchedItems.add(tag);
                } else {
                setChildToggleCheckedState(false);
                    mToggleSwitchedItems.remove(tag);
                }
                //update our list when switch toggled
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        //set the text for our child header here
        viewHolder.textView.setText("All Teams");
    }
    else {

        //depending on toggle state set our remaining text colors
        if (!getChildToggleCheckedState()) {
            viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.navDrawerInactiveText));
        }
        else {
            viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.navDrawerDisabledText));
        }


        //set our text for all remaining children
        expandedListText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition - 1);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(expandedListText);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
    return (this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .size() + 1);
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.expandableListTitle.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_list_group, null);
    }
    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

**The Activity did not change to make this work.**